# Why it throws stackOverflowError when the getInstance method is not static

Tags: java, class, oop, static-methods

Class A Sample 1

```
public class A {

    private  A instance = new A();

    public A() {
    }

    public  A getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

}
```

Class A Sample 2

```
public class A {

    private static A instance = new A();

    public A() {
    }

    public static A getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Main Class

```
    public class MainClass {


      public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
     }

}
```

When I try to run above program with using Class A Sample 1, it throws `stackOverflowError Exception` but when I try to run with using Class A Sample 2
it run without any errors. Anyone who can explain to me  with details why it throws error when I using Class A sample 1? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
private A instance = new A();

public A() {
}
```

This is equivalent to code which calls `new A()` in the constructor. It's effectively the same as:

```
private A instance;

public A() {
    this.instance = new A();
}
```

Do you see how this causes infinite recursion? The constructor `A()` invokes itself.

---

```
private static A instance = new A();
```

On the other hand, when you have a static variable it's only instantiated once when the class itself is loaded, rather than every time an instance of the class is created. It's as if you had done it in a static initialization block—which only runs a single time.

```
private static A instance;

static {
    A.instance = new A();
}
```

Notice how `this.instance` has become `A.instance`. There's only a single class-wide `instance` variable here versus a per-instance copy in the other version.

Comment: Nice answer to this question.

Comment: yep this is the more complete answer :) +1

Answer (score 1):

Because in the non-`static` case, you're invoking `new A()` **every time** a new `A` is created...

Answer (score 1):

`Sample 1` causes an infinite loop since every time you create an instance of `A` it will create another instance of `A` until you run out of stack space. Since you use `static` in `Sample 2` the member variable `instance` will be created once.

Comment: Why it causes an infinite loop?